# Button affecting selected div without using uniq ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a script for my buttons that would only work on the block in which this button is located without using ID ans .getElemetByID methods?
Here is an example in which I use ID and only for one button, but I want to make all the buttons expand their parent blocks.

```js
function toggle() {

  var tBlock = document.getElementById("textblock");
  var tText = document.getElementById("text");

  if (tBlock.style.height === "100px" && tText.style.height === "60px") {
    tBlock.style.height = "auto";
    tText.style.height = "auto";
  } else {
    tBlock.style.height = "100px";
    tText.style.height = "60px";
  }
}
```

```css
.docText {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.docTextContent {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="docText" id="textblock">
  <div class="docTextContent" id="text">
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn" onclick="toggle()">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="docText">
  <div class="docTextContent">
    TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="docText">
  <div class="docTextContent">
    TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  TextTextText
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn">Show</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by retrieving all of the toggle buttons via class name and then loop through them while binding a click handler. Here is a working example:

```js
// GET ALL TOGGLES
var toggles = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle_btn");

// LOOP THROUGH EACH TOGGLE AND APPLY AN EVENT LISTENER
for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
  toggles[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // GET .docTextContent ELEMENT
    var tBlock = this.parentElement.children[0];

    // IF .docTextContent IS "CLOSED"
    if (tBlock.style.height === "60px" || tBlock.style.height === "") {
      tBlock.style.height = "auto";
    }

    // .docTextContent IS "OPEN"
    else {
      tBlock.style.height = "60px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.docText {
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.docTextContent {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="docText" id="textblock">
  <div class="docTextContent" id="text">
    TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="docText">
  <div class="docTextContent">
    TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="docText">
  <div class="docTextContent">
    TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText TextTextText
  </div>
  <button class="toggle_btn">Show</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code.

```
<button onclick=“function()”></button>
```